# SipManager.setRegistrationListener throwing null pointer

Tags: android, sip

hi i am trying to make a sip call using android api the code is below. the setRegistration Listener method is throwing an nullpointer for my sipprofile but the profile prints fine so am at a bit of a loss as to why its throwing the error. am very new to android this is my first project so any help would be great thanks.

```
 public void MakeACall(String a){
    try {

        String ad="calling "+a;//a is peer address
        res1.setText(ad);//res1 is textview
        //sp() is method to generate profile
        String b=sp("name","getonsip.com","pass").getUriString();//local profile
        res1.setText(b);            
        System.out.println(b);//prints the sip profile fine
        SipProfile mSipProfile = sp("name","getonsip.com","pass");
        SipManager mSipManager =SipManager.newInstance(MainActivity.this);          
        mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(b,//nullpointer error is thrown here<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                new SipRegistrationListener() {
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                res1.setText("Registering with SIP Server...");
            }

            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                res1.setText("Ready");
            }

            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                    String errorMessage) {
                res1.setText("Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
            }
        });

        SipAudioCall.Listener whatWasThat = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {               
        @Override
        public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
        call.startAudio();
        call.setSpeakerMode(true);
        call.toggleMute();
        res1.setText("calling");
        }
        @Override
        public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {                
            res1.setText("ended");
        }
        };


        mSipManager.makeAudioCall(sp("name","getonsip.com","pass").getUriString(), 
                sp("other","getonsip.com","pass").getUriString(), whatWasThat, 30);

    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("error with profile string thing");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SipException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//end makecall()
```

here is logcat

```
    03-29 15:05:20.679: D/AndroidRuntime(11466): Shutting down VM
    03-29 15:05:20.679: W/dalvikvm(11466): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466): java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at com.example.test2.MainActivity.MakeACall(MainActivity.java:51)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at com.example.test2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    03-29 15:05:20.679: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running sipmanager out of the thread. check this out. [Android SipManager throwing NullPointException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687385/android-sipmanager-throwing-nullpointexception)

Comment: thanks for link but i am not using it in a thread but thanks i did do a search for this topic dont know how i did not find that

Comment: well obiously its in a thread but app is not threaded yet maybe im wrong but aint all functions on a computer a thread so how could it be run outside of thread as link says

Comment: tought i found the problem i never called mSipManager.open(mSipProfile); before mSipManager.setreg...; however that is now throwing nullpointer so obiousley my sip profile is null but it returns correct .getUriString(); so im at a loss it returns correct data but is null??